# Adding index to a database change the results of a query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to add an index for a simple query, however adding it change results. Is it possible that indexes impact query results?

When I delete back the index, the results come back the way they were before.

The query is as simple as this:

```
SELECT `gid`.`num_version_contrat` AS `num_version_contrat`, MAX(`gid`.`date_quittancement_echeance`) AS `max_date_quittancement_echeance`,`gid`.`montant_ht_actualise_echeance` AS `dernier_montant`
FROM `gid`
WHERE `gid`.num_version_contrat = "100313 V.0"
GROUP BY `gid`.`num_version_contrat`
ORDER BY `gid`.`num_version_contrat`
```

Without the indexes the results are:

> "num_version_contrat", "max_date_quittancement_echeance", "dernier_montant" :
>
> "100313 V.0", "2018-04-01", "32744"

Adding the index:

```
CREATE INDEX `gid_idx_group_by_index` ON `gid` (`num_version_contrat`, `date_quittancement_echeance`, `montant_ht_actualise_echeance`)
```

Results with index:

> "num_version_contrat", "max_date_quittancement_echeance", "dernier_montant" :
>
> "100313 V.0", "2018-04-01", "2067.64"

Do you understand why the results are different in both case?

Comment: Well, what is the correct result? Does the query return more than one line and you are only looking at the first one? Adding an index might well change the order the matching rows are returned. Also your `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` make no sense given your `WHERE`-condition....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a field in the select clause that is not in the group by: `gid`.`montant_ht_actualise_echeance`

This is a very dangerous feature of MySQL and MariaDB that can give unexpected results as you have found out.

Other Databases will refuse your query, but unless your SQL mode contains "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", MariaDB will accept the query and then give you the first value for that it encounters while reading.

Adding an index changes the order records are retrieved in, so you get something different. In fact, even adding/updating/deleting *other* records may change the result of a group, because it might change in which block a record resides.

You can fix your query by adding `gid`.`montant_ht_actualise_echeance` to the Group by statement.

Alternatively you can pick an aggegrate function to calculate the sum, max, first_value or last_value.

In reply to the comment:

GROUP BY means "For every combination of these fields, make one record". So if you have "GROUP BY year, month" you will get one record for each year and month combination that is found in the table. 
Additionally, you put all values here that you know have a unique value within the groups. That means "quarter" should go here, since a month always has a unique value for quarter. "Company name" should also go there if there is only one value for all records.

For all other fields, you need to tell the database how to treat the multiple values that are found. Numeric fields are easy: you can SUM(price) or COUNT(id), etc. For text fields, you need to choose: MIN, MAX (by alphabetical order), FIRST_VALUE (that is what you have now, implicitly) or even GROUP_CONCAT to append all values into one string.

To get the value of gid.montant_ht_actualise_echeance associated with the last (max) `gid`.`date_quittancement_echeance`, you need to first identify the records that have the max date and use those to select the desired values from the table.

In MySQL/MariaDB it's most often done by self-joining the table. If the table has a unqiue key/id column, use that to join, but if not, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT `gid`.`num_version_contrat` AS `num_version_contrat`,
`gid`.`date_quittancement_echeance` AS `max_date_quittancement_echeance`, 
`gid`.`montant_ht_actualise_echeance` AS `dernier_montant`
FROM `gid`
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `gid`.`num_version_contrat` AS `num_version_contrat`, 
    MAX(`gid`.`date_quittancement_echeance`) AS max_date
    FROM `gid`
    GROUP BY `gid`.`num_version_contrat`
) last_dates
ON `gid`.`num_version_contrat` = `last_dates`.`num_version_contrat`
AND `gid`.`date_quittancement_echeance` = `last_dates`.`max_date`
WHERE `gid`.num_version_contrat = "100313 V.0"

ORDER BY `gid`.`num_version_contrat`
```

The first part selects the fields that you want. The second part finds only the max_dates per contract version and the INNER JOIN keeps only records found in both, removing all records that DON'T have the max_date.

This assumes the WHERE clause is only for testing and will be removed later.
Otherwise, the whole group by does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser ! Before this, I was looking get the max date of each `num_version_contrat` and then fin the `dernier_montant`, now I get multiple results per `num_version_contrat`. How should I build my query ? @Cyrus

Comment: For that, you need a somewhat different query. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand how I could build such a query, can you point me somewhere so I can figure it out ? Thank you for your long anwser ! @Cyrus

Comment: Try the one I just added. It may need small adjustments, since I couldn't check it of course, but the structure you need is there.

Comment: Okay, it's all clear now, thank you so much ! @Cyrus .